# Installing react-native using create-react-native-app gives error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, node-modules

I want to learn React-native and I am following the [official docs.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) and I am using `create-react-native-app` for installation.

I am also working for a project in reactjs which is also installed using `create-react-app`. 
When I tried to install react-native using cmd:

```
npm install -g create-react-native-app
```

I see the following error

```js
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

My mac already has a `node_modules` which is created during Reactjs Installation.

And when I run `npm install create-react-native-app` the modules are installed but the cmd for creating react native app didn't get recognized.

```
$create-react-native-app hello
```

`-bash: create-react-native-app: command not found`

Is it possible to work both in react-native and reactjs?

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777 node_modules
let me know if still facing issue . this is the permission issue

Comment: what command did you issue to get the error?

Comment: @RaviR npm install -g create-react-native-app

Comment: No that didn't work @anilsidhu

Comment: when you ran @anilsidhu's recommendation, did you point to full path? i.e. `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` and not just `node_modules`?

Comment: sudo npm install -g create-react-native-app try this command . it should be work .

Comment: because -g used for global and we need root access. sudo  will provide root access to your command . so just use sudo in the front of your command

Comment: That works @anilsidhu Would be nice if u post this as answer.

Comment: please give ne thumps up to comment if find it helpful :) and  for good question i already gives you thumps up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything with -g requires a global install and requires sudo access. Because this installs globally.

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-native-app
```

Comment: it was my answer :D

Comment: Anila Sindhu. I did see that earlier. I knew the answer before you knew it. I asked him the question as to what command he is using when you were saying that directory had to be chmodded. While I was writing the answer you commented. Thats the diff. I felt I deserved it otherwise I would have said so.